# .htaccess redirect some parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameter-passing

My existing link structure is

```
http://www.domain.com/compare-smart-phone/?compare_products=SP0006++SP0002++&count_products=2&prawns-details_length=10&chk_compare=SP0006&chk_compare=SP0002&btn_compareproducts=Compare
```

I am able to redirect by passing all parameters. But I want to pass only few parameters to the new URL.

I want to redirect this to

```
http://www.domain.com/smart-phone/?compare_products=SP0006++SP0002++
```

Please help me in writing the redirect rule for this.

Comment: Why you feel need to do this? It has not any affect on SEO optimization. Can you describe more?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the document root of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^compare_products=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^compare-smart-phone/?$ /smart-phone/?compare_products=%1 [R=301,L]
```